# Angular - Project from stackblitz not working on computer

Tags: angular

I want to repeat this project here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rltfm5?file=src%2Fapp%2Fvalidators%2Frequired.validator.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fvalidators%2Fmatch.validator.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fvalidators%2Findex.ts,tsconfig.json

I copy it to my computer but it doesn't work. How to make it work?

I am creating a new project on the computer. I copy these files to a new project and it doesn't work.

```
"C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd" run start

> match-ang@0.0.0 start
> ng serve

√ Browser application bundle generation complete.   

Initial Chunk Files   | Names         |  Raw Size   
vendor.js             | vendor        |   2.06 MB | 
polyfills.js          | polyfills     | 318.05 kB | 
styles.css, styles.js | styles        | 210.08 kB | 
main.js               | main          |  20.57 kB | 
runtime.js            | runtime       |   6.51 kB | 

                      | Initial Total |   2.60 MB

Build at: 2022-10-03T21:11:26.389Z - Hash: 1f529fd68fe4789e - Time: 3479ms

Error: src/app/app.component.html:8:60 - error TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'.

8   <small class="text-danger" *ngIf="formGroup.get('email').touched && formGroup.get('email').errors">
                                                             ~~~~~~~

  src/app/app.component.ts:7:16
    7   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component AppComponent.


Error: src/app/app.component.html:8:94 - error TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'.

8   <small class="text-danger" *ngIf="formGroup.get('email').touched && formGroup.get('email').errors">
                                                                                               ~~~~~~

  src/app/app.component.ts:7:16
    7   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component AppComponent.


Error: src/app/app.component.html:9:31 - error TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'.

9     {{ formGroup.get('email').errors.message }}
                                ~~~~~~

  src/app/app.component.ts:7:16
    7   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component AppComponent.


Error: src/app/app.component.html:9:38 - error TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'.

9     {{ formGroup.get('email').errors.message }}
                                       ~~~~~~~

  src/app/app.component.ts:7:16
    7   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component AppComponent.


Error: src/app/app.component.html:9:38 - error TS4111: Property 'message' comes from an index signature, so it must be accessed with ['mess
age'].

9     {{ formGroup.get('email').errors.message }}
                                       ~~~~~~~

  src/app/app.component.ts:7:16
    7   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component AppComponent.


Error: src/app/app.component.html:19:67 - error TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'.

19   <small class="text-danger" *ngIf="formGroup.get('confirmEmail').touched && formGroup.get('confirmEmail').errors">
                                                                     ~~~~~~~

  src/app/app.component.ts:7:16
    7   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component AppComponent.


Error: src/app/app.component.html:19:108 - error TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'.

19   <small class="text-danger" *ngIf="formGroup.get('confirmEmail').touched && formGroup.get('confirmEmail').errors">
                                                                                                              ~~~~~~

  src/app/app.component.ts:7:16
    7   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component AppComponent.


Error: src/app/app.component.html:20:38 - error TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'.

20     {{ formGroup.get('confirmEmail').errors.message }}
                                        ~~~~~~

  src/app/app.component.ts:7:16
    7   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component AppComponent.


Error: src/app/app.component.html:20:45 - error TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'.

20     {{ formGroup.get('confirmEmail').errors.message }}
                                               ~~~~~~~

  src/app/app.component.ts:7:16
    7   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component AppComponent.


Error: src/app/app.component.html:20:45 - error TS4111: Property 'message' comes from an index signature, so it must be accessed with ['mes
sage'].

20     {{ formGroup.get('confirmEmail').errors.message }}
                                               ~~~~~~~

  src/app/app.component.ts:7:16
    7   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component AppComponent.


Error: src/app/app.component.html:28:63 - error TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'.

28   <small class="text-danger" *ngIf="formGroup.get('password').touched && formGroup.get('password').errors">
                                                                 ~~~~~~~

  src/app/app.component.ts:7:16
    7   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component AppComponent.


Error: src/app/app.component.html:28:100 - error TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'.

28   <small class="text-danger" *ngIf="formGroup.get('password').touched && formGroup.get('password').errors">
                                                                                                      ~~~~~~

  src/app/app.component.ts:7:16
    7   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component AppComponent.


Error: src/app/app.component.html:29:34 - error TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'.

29     {{ formGroup.get('password').errors.message }}
                                    ~~~~~~

  src/app/app.component.ts:7:16
    7   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component AppComponent.


Error: src/app/app.component.html:29:41 - error TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'.

29     {{ formGroup.get('password').errors.message }}
                                           ~~~~~~~

  src/app/app.component.ts:7:16
    7   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component AppComponent.


Error: src/app/app.component.html:29:41 - error TS4111: Property 'message' comes from an index signature, so it must be accessed with ['mes
sage'].

29     {{ formGroup.get('password').errors.message }}
                                           ~~~~~~~

  src/app/app.component.ts:7:16
    7   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component AppComponent.


Error: src/app/app.component.html:37:71 - error TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'.

37   <small class="text-danger" *ngIf=" formGroup.get('confirmPassword').touched && formGroup.get('confirmPassword').errors">
                                                                         ~~~~~~~

  src/app/app.component.ts:7:16
    7   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component AppComponent.


Error: src/app/app.component.html:37:115 - error TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'.

37   <small class="text-danger" *ngIf=" formGroup.get('confirmPassword').touched && formGroup.get('confirmPassword').errors">
                                                                                                                     ~~~~~~

  src/app/app.component.ts:7:16
    7   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component AppComponent.


Error: src/app/app.component.html:38:41 - error TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'.

38     {{ formGroup.get('confirmPassword').errors.message }}
                                           ~~~~~~

  src/app/app.component.ts:7:16
    7   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component AppComponent.


Error: src/app/app.component.html:38:48 - error TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'.

38     {{ formGroup.get('confirmPassword').errors.message }}
                                                  ~~~~~~~

  src/app/app.component.ts:7:16
    7   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component AppComponent.


Error: src/app/app.component.html:38:48 - error TS4111: Property 'message' comes from an index signature, so it must be accessed with ['mes
sage'].

38     {{ formGroup.get('confirmPassword').errors.message }}
                                                  ~~~~~~~

  src/app/app.component.ts:7:16
    7   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component AppComponent.




** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **


× Failed to compile.
```

Comment: Turning off strict mode in tsconfig might help. Stackblitz is a bit ‘loose’..

Comment: It does not help

Comment: The problem is the "strictMode", but  **not** turn off else use the safe operator in .html `?`, e.g. `formGroup.get('confirmEmail')?.touched` or `formGroup.get('confirmEmail')?.errors?.message`, take careful when declare a variable to give a value,...